# Calculus with Constants

Tags: calculus

An electric current, I, in amps, is given by 
I=cos(wt)+√(8)sin(wt), 
where w≠0 is a constant. What are the maximum and minimum values of I?

I have tried finding the derivative, but after that, I do not know how to solve for 0 because of the constant w.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well David,you can convert this function into one trigonometric function by multiplying and dividing it by

√(1^2 + 8) i.e, 3. So your function becomes like this

```
I = 3*(1/3 cos(wt) + √8/3 sin(wt))
  = 3* sin(wt + atan(1/√8))
```

Now, you can easily say its maximum value is 
    I = 3 amp
and minimum value is
    I = 0 amp.